# Que comando posso utilizar para excluir um item de um repeater em c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou tentando realizar a exclusão de um item de um repeater, este item é uma pessoa "cadastrada". Porque não há um banco de dados envolvido

tenho conhecimento do Repeater1.Controls.Remove, porém este não exclui.

As informações como: nome, e-mail, cpf estão "registradas" em uma list.
Que outro comando posso utilizar??

Obs: não posso fazer uso de JavaScripit nesta página

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar um if no repeater. Acredito que isso deva lhe ajudar.
Por exemplo o código aqui tem um if do currentItem.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <% if ( (CurrentItemCount % 2) == 0 ) { %?>
            <tr id="itemRow" runat="server">
            <% } %>
                <td>
                    Some data
                </td>
            <% if ( (CurrentItemCount % 2) == 0 ) { %?>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Pra vc buscar informações do item da lista vc pode usar a chamada direto para variavel.

Assim:

```
<asp:repeater runat="server">
<itemtemplate>
    <%# if ((bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsEmpty")) { %>
       ALO
    <%#}%>
</itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Mais info: [https://forums.asp.net/t/1766065.aspx?if+statement+in+repeater+control](https://forums.asp.net/t/1766065.aspx?if%20statement%20in%20repeater%20control)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: =) só dá o ok nas flechas alí. valews